# Intellij won't start spring boot application

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot

I'm facing problem while starting a spring boot app on intellij and it fails with below message:
    Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:49784', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 255
Anyone has faced this before?

Comment: What Run Configuration are you using?

Comment: I'm just using Spring boot plugin and configured SpringBoot main class.

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions that lack sufficient information to diagnose the problem.* Please edit your post accordingly to add sufficient detail so that people may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I figured it out. There was a library which was registered as ApplicationStart event listener in Spring boot. That listener was was failing and there was code which was stopping the process with System.exit.